# Variables de entorno devuelven valor vacío en Liquidsoap

Tags: ubuntu, variables-globales

He configurado liquidsoap para enviar las contraseñas usando variables de entorno a los efectos de no publicarlas en texto plano en el script .liq.
No consigo que se lea su valor en el script, siempre me devuelven un vacío.

```
log("Variable SOURCE_PASSW: " ^ getenv("SOURCE_PASSW"))
log("Variable PASSWORD_DJ: " ^ getenv("PASSWORD_DJ"))
log("Variable PASSWORD_ADMIN: " ^ getenv("PASSWORD_ADMIN"))

2023/08/22 09:40:25 [lang:3] Variable SOURCE_PASSW: 
2023/08/22 09:40:25 [lang:3] Variable PASSWORD_DJ: 
2023/08/22 09:40:25 [lang:3] Variable PASSWORD_ADMIN:
```

He definido las variables editando el archivo `/etc/environment` a los efectos de que sean globales y estén accesibles en cualquier entorno siempre.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
TELNET_USERNAME=client_metadata
TELNET_PASSWORD=985421
ADMIN_ICECAST=admin
PASSWORD_ADMIN=9632541
PASSWORD_DJ=20548798
SOURCE_PASSW=05897445
RELAY_PASSW=635478
```

Si miro su valor con cualquier usuario de linux en cualquier ruta me muestran los valores:

```
icecast2@ip-17x-xx-xx-xxx:~/liquidsoap-daemon/script$ echo $PASSWORD_ADMIN

9632541
```

Versión de Icecast2: Icecast 2.4.4
Versión de Liquidsoap: Liquidsoap 2.1.4 (instalado con OCaml Package Manager (opam))

```
icecast2@ip-17x-xx-xx-xxx:~/liquidsoap-daemon$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Si desean algún dato adicional no duden en preguntarme.
Desde ya agradezo la ayuda que me puedan brindar para solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución y la publico a los solos efectos de ayudar a otros que se encuentren en la misma situación que yo.

Antes que nada olvidé mencionar que uso liquisoap como demonio, simplemente edité la configuración del servicio, con el comando `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/main-liquidsoap.service`
Y agregué en la etiqueta [Service] el comando `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment`
Y eso hizo la magia! :)